# Is "煽りを喰らう" an idiom/set-phrase? If so what does it mean?

Tags: set-phrases, idioms

I came across the phrase in a novel, I've never heard of it before and am curious to know if it's an idiom/set-phrase and what context it could be used in.

In this novel for example two characters are having a conversation about higher-ups suspiciously intervening in the business of the agency they work with (科学技術庁), one calls the higher-ups arrogant and says they are incapable of outwitting him. The other responds with the above aforementioned phrase.

> "巫山戯た事を抜かす連中だ、まったく。たかが100年程度の歴史を支えてきたというだけで、己以上の才覚を意のままに操れるなどと思い上がっているのだから"
>
> "その煽りを喰らった科学技術庁も大変すね"

Answer (score 3):

煽りを喰らう is the same as [煽りを食う](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%85%BD%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%86). In general, 喰らう, 食らう, 喰う and 食う all [convey roughly the same idea](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52448/5010), but くらう is used more often in the sense of "to take (damage, etc)". In this case it says 科学技術庁 was not directly related to the matter mentioned in the conversation, but was unexpectedly (and negatively) affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

煽｛あお｝りを喰｛く｝らう is an idiom that means:

> to suffer a blast or indirect blow, to be subject to the surplus force of an impetus

English idioms would include: Bear the brunt, suffer the aftermath, suffer the consequences, bear the burden, deal with the fallout, etc.

So, the essence of the final statement would be 'The Science and Technology Agency that bears the brunt of it (has to deal with the aftermath) will also be in a difficult position.'